# Use Package variable instead of creating local variable

Tags: go

Consider following code snippet:

```
var name string

func init() {
   name = "ginny"
}

func test() {
   name, err := ...<some method>..
}
```

In the method test, **name** is created as new local variable.

How do I make the test method to use the package variable **name** instead of creating new local variable?

Comment: The shorthand operator `:=` *always* creates a new variable. If you want to use an existing variable, use `=`.

Comment: OK that explains. I interpreted the ability to use existing variable name to the left of short hand operator in different way. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `:=` operator always creates new variables. You can it like this:

```
var name string

func init() {
   name = "ginny"
}

func test() {
   var err error
   name, err = ...<some method>..
}
```